# Import Firestore dependencies and types to node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm recently updating my cloud functions to TypeScript after the talks on the FirebaseSummit of this year.

All my code looks quite cool, but I'm having some problems trying to recover the types of Firestore API, such `QuerySnapshot` , `DocumentReference`...

```
async function getEventsMadeByUser(userId: string): Promise<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentSnapshot[]> {
    const eventsMadeByUserQuery = await instance.collection('PrivateUserData')
        .doc(userId).collection(EVENTS)
        .where('interactionUser', '==', userId).get();
    return eventsMadeByUserQuery.docs;
}
```

Right now my IDE (WebStorm) is not getting the types for `FirebaseFirestore`. This is how my `package.json` looks:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5.4.3",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.0.37",
    "typescript": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "deploy": "tsc && firebase deploy --only functions"
  },
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "private": true
}
```

I have already tried to add [@firebase-firestore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/firestore) and nothing, it's not working. What is the right dependency to achieve this?

Comment: That's not Firebase Firestore. Also it's something from 3y ago. Firestore was released a month ago.

Comment: What do your import statements look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured it out! The `firebase-admin` module is just a simple wrapper that initializes Firestore for you. To get the real Firestore, add `"@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.9.0"` to your `package.json`. You can admire those beautiful types here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/master/types/firestore.d.ts.

Comment: use `import { Firestore } from "@google-cloud/firestore";` to get type defs.

Answer (score 2):

```js
import { DocumentData } from '@firebase/firestore-types'
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that you can get the types directly from `firebase-admin` without adding additional packages:

```js
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin'

const iAmConsumingDB = (db: firestore.Firestore) => {
  // do something
}

const iAmConsumingADocumentReference = (reference: firestore.DocumentReference) => {
  // do something
}
```